# Function Display Questions

Tags: c++

I was tasked to write a program to display a field of stars (*) based on the user inputted data. I got the code to work, but my instructor asked to put them in at least two functions. The displaybanner function is not working. getData runs and asks the user to enter the values but then the program stops after the inputs. What seems to be going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void displaybanner(int numrows=0, int numcolums=0, int numfields=0);

void getData(int numrows=0, int numcolumns=0, int numfields=0);

const char c = '*';



int main(void)
{
    getData();
    displaybanner();


}

void getData(int numrows,int numcolumns,int numfields)
{

    cout << "Welcome to the banner creation program!" << endl;

    cout << "Enter the number of rows (1 - 5) --> ";
    cin >> numrows;

    if(numrows<1 || numrows>5){
        cout << "Your entered value is outside the range!" << endl;
        cout << "Program will now halt..." << endl;
        exit(0);}


    cout << "Enter the number of columns (5 - 50) --> ";
    cin >> numcolumns;

    if(numcolumns<5 || numcolumns>50){
        cout << "Your entered value is outside the range!" << endl;
        cout << "Program will now halt..." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    cout << "Enter the number of rows (3 - 10) --> ";
    cin >> numfields;

    if(numfields<3 || numrows>10){
        cout << "Your entered value is outside the range!" << endl;
        cout << "Program will now halt..." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

}

void displaybanner(int numfields, int numrows, int numcolumns)
{
for (int i = 0; i < numfields; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < numrows; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < numcolumns; k++) {
      cout << c;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl << endl << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Think about what the arguments to the functions mean. In particular, if you don't give anything to `getData()`, it will print 0 stars, i.e. nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work, because you're only modifying temporary/local values within your functions. To fix this, you have to pass your parameters by reference (using either a pointer or reference).

Easiest way would probably be using references, e.g. change

```
void getData(int numfields, int numrows, int numcolumns)
```

to

```
void getData(int &numfields, int &numrows, int &numcolumns)
```

This will ensure to keep all changes you did to these parameters, even when returning to the calling function. Note that you can't use default parameters, but you only have to do it where you want to return values through parameters.

Your main function should then look like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int fields, rows, cols;
    getData(fields, rows, cols);
    displaybanner(fields, rows, cols);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default arguments to `displaybanner` are all zero:

```
void displaybanner(int numrows = 0, int numcolums = 0, int numfields = 0);
```

And since you're calling this function in the main module without any arguments, the succession of loops will not execute (since the index variables are 0 and their limits are 0). To make it work, pass arguments to `displaybanner` or make its default arguments greater than 0.